# Audio Splitting Program in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydub

I have some code that is meant to split an longer mp3 file into a series of 10 second mp3 files and I am using Jupyter Notebook for this code if that matters. The code is as follows:

```py
from pydub import AudioSegment
import os

def split_mp3_by_seconds(input_file, output_folder, segment_length=10):
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(input_file, format="mp3")
    total_length = len(audio)

    for i in range(0, total_length, segment_length * 1000):
        segment = audio[i:i + segment_length * 1000]
        output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, f"segment_{i // 1000}.mp3")
        segment.export(output_path, format="mp3")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_file_path = r"C:\Users\reape\Desktop\english1\english1.mp3"
    output_folder_path = r"C:\Users\reape\Desktop\english1"

split_mp3_by_seconds(input_file_path, output_folder_path)
```

This is giving me a gigantic file not found error, but I have tried multiple file pathings and have no idea what the issue is.

I have tried changing the file pathing from

```
"C:\Users\reape\Desktop\english1\english1.mp3"
```

to

```
"C:\\Users\\reape\\Desktop\\english1\\english1.mp3"
```

and

```
"C:/Users/reape/Desktop/english1/english1.mp3"
```

but none of these seem to work. This seems to be an issue with the file pathing, but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: check that the file exists with the `os` module.

Comment: please post the error message...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For debugging help, we need the error. For reference see [mre]. For more tips, like how to write a good title, check out [ask]. You can [edit].

Comment: If it helps, the file path syntax isn't part of the issue since everything you're showing here is the same. That is, except the one with single backslashes and no `r` prefix (which will cause a syntax error), but I guess you just missed the `r` prefix when copy-pasting.

Answer (score 0):

The file either exists or it does not. There are various functions in the `os` module which can help establish file existence (i show two methods).

so, here is a simple way of checking for that...

```py
import os

f = 'G:/path/to/the/file.mp3'
if os.path.isfile(f):
    print('File exists')
else:
    print('File does not exist')
```

or with this:

```py
if os.path.exists(f):
    print('File exists')
else:
    print('File does not exist')
```

It seems that the paths (for windows) would work fine. So a few potential errors:

- drive letter is different
- typo (on windows can do copy path to avoid this)

Beyond the above, the question show the actual error message.